# Jest not covering with setinterval

Tags: typescript, jestjs, setinterval

*I have tried to mock the below actual component which is written using react typescript, getting an error saying too many renders while covering Else path and setinterval function in if condition is not covered too, please help me in covering it to 100% as of now it is 80%*

**Actual Component in react Typescript**

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
//import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Animate } from "react-move";

interface animateProps {
  duration ?:any;
  repeat?:any;
  valueEnd?:any;
  valueStart?:any;
  children?:any;
  easingFunction?:any;
}

export const AnimatedProgressProvider : React.FC<animateProps> = (props: animateProps) => {
  const {
    repeat,
    duration,
    valueEnd,
    valueStart,
    children,
    easingFunction,
  } = props;

 var interval :any = 0;
  const [isAnimated, handleIsanimated] = useState(false);
 

  React.useEffect(()=> {
    if (repeat) {
      interval =setInterval(() => {
        handleIsanimated(false)
      }, duration * 1000); 
     
    } else {
      handleIsanimated(true)
    }
    clearInterval(interval);
  })

    return (
    
      <Animate
        start={() => ({
          value: valueStart
        })}
        update={() => ({
          value: [
           isAnimated ? valueEnd : valueStart
          ],
          timing: {
            duration: duration ,
            // ease: easingFunction
          }
        })}
      >
        {( value:any ) => children(value)}
      </Animate>
    );
  }
```

**Jest Test Case - setInterval function is not covered and else path is throwing error**

```
import React ,{useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Enzyme, { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { AnimatedProgressProvider } from './AnimatedProgressProvider';
import { createFalse } from "typescript";
import { fn } from "jquery";

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

let duration :any;
let repeat:any;
let valueEnd:any;
let valueStart:any;
let children:any;
let easingFunction:any;
let interval:any;

const useEffectMock = jest.fn(fn => fn());

const props = {
  duration: 1000,
  valueStart: 0,
  valueEnd: 95,
  children: valueStart,
  easingFunction,
  repeat: false
};

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe("Render Animated progress Component", ()=>{
  let interval :any = 0;
  const handleIsanimated = jest.fn();
  const useStateMock:any = (isAnimated:any) => [isAnimated, handleIsanimated]
  jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect').mockImplementation((fn) => fn());
  jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockImplementation(useStateMock);
  beforeEach(()=>{
  });
  
  const wrapperAnimatedProgress = shallow(<AnimatedProgressProvider duration={'1000'} valueStart={'0'} valueEnd={'95%'} children={valueStart} easingFunction repeat={false}/>)

  it("Render Animated Progress Interval else", ()=>{
    const customProps1 = {...props, repeat:false}
    const wrapperAnimatedProgress1 = shallow(<AnimatedProgressProvider {...customProps1}/>)
    expect(wrapperAnimatedProgress1.contains(0)).toBe(true);
   wrapperAnimatedProgress.equals(interval);
    expect(handleIsanimated).toBeCalled;
  });
  it("Animate project not to be null if", done => {
    const customProps = {...props, repeat:true}
    const wrapperAnimatedProgress = shallow(<AnimatedProgressProvider {...customProps}/>);
    expect(wrapperAnimatedProgress.contains(0)).toBe(false);
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
    wrapperAnimatedProgress.equals(interval);
    wrapperAnimatedProgress.props().start();
    wrapperAnimatedProgress.props().update();
    wrapperAnimatedProgress.props().children.value;
    jest.useRealTimers();
  done();
  });

});
```

**Error it is throwing as too many re-renders and setInterval function is not covered too saying function not covered mouse over**
Render Animated progress Component › encountered a declaration exception

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

  33 |
  34 |     } else {
> 35 |       handleIsanimated(true)
     |       ^
  36 |     }
  37 |     clearInterval(interval);
  38 |   })
```